# iOS : imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection not working for GIF images

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

**imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection** is used to flip images(such as arrows) when the phone is set to a RTL language.

It's not working for GIF images, where as it's working fine for static images.

```
button.image = UIImage.gifImageWithName("placeholder_icon")?.imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()
```

I am using this helper code to load GIF images : [link](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift/blob/master/GIF-Swift/iOSDevCenters%2BGIF.swift)

> Do i need to add a different image for RTL language?

Comment: iOS has no support for display of gifs. Your `gifImageWithName` comes from someone else's code. https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift

Comment: @matt i have added helper code link to load the GIF images. Please read the full question.

Comment: But the point is that this is third-party code. This is between you and the author of that code. You cannot expect this sort of image to respond to `imageFlipped` if a response to `imageFlipped` is not built into it. And it isn't.